# php get string length and replace first and last 3 characters WITHOUT using a function

Tags: php

I am trying to get the length of a string and replace its first and last 3 characters with a star sign (*) and get the string length WITHOUT using any PHP build in functions.

```
strlen - substr - preg_replace
```

Example: `$string = "123456789"; $new_string = "***456***";`

Is it possible?

I have checked many tutorials and couldn't figure it out. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: @u_mulder see the question without using any build in php functions .

Comment: Is this some sort of homework?

Comment: @RamaKrishna Answer is __still__: yes it is possible.

Comment: I still wonder how ? could you please give show code for this ?

Comment: No, it is not a homework. But, I would like to know how. And that other question doesn't show how to get the length of it or replace the last 3 characters.

Comment: With php7.1 there's no even need for a loop) Whoops. i said __loop__?

Comment: I'm not a professoinal of PHP, but if it has exceptions, you can just loop on the characters of the string, and when an exception occurs, you're at the end :)

Comment: @hobaa1385r, is `isset` function allowed in your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you don't want to use any PHP functions. However, it is still possible.

```
   <?php

function privacy($string)
{

    //get the string length   

    $i = 0;

    /*  
    while (isset($string[$i])) {
    $i++;
    }
    */

    while ($string[$i] !== "") {
        $i++;
    }

    //replace the first and last 3 characters of the $string with a star
    //if the length is bigger than or equals to 6
    if ($i >= 6) {
        for ($x = 0; $x < 3; $x++) {
            $string[$x]      = "*";
            $string[$i - $x] = "*";
        }
    }
    return $i . "<br>" . $string;
}

echo privacy("123456789");

?>
```

Will echo out this

```
 9
 ***456***
```

I think it is the easiest way to get the string length and replace the first and last 3 characters without confusion. So far!

Good luck!

Comment: Using `isset`? Is it allowed?

Comment: Yaay! This is what I wanted exactly. isset is not a problem for me as long as we don't use strlen - preg_replace_substr as I mentioned. Because else I would need to write the string length manually. Thanks so muchhh!

Comment: then why you have specify **WITHOUT using any PHP build in functions.** in your question. Also better answer is there. this answer has static value `if ($i >= 6) {` what if string is bigger?

Comment: I gave a list of what functions I don't want to use. Anyway, u_mulder you posted isset in the first place but your method is confusing and way longer.

Comment: Way longer? Lol.

Comment: For your convenience guys, I have updated my answer adding a new method to get the string length without using a php function.

Comment: @B.Desai If the string length is less than 6, its characters won't be replaced. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Universal solution:

```
$string = "123456789";
$i = 0;
$limit = 3;
while (isset($string[$i])) {
    if ($i < $limit) {
        $string[$i] = '*';
    }
    $i++;
}
// you can rewrite this as loop
$string[$i - 1] = '*';
$string[$i - 2] = '*';
$string[$i - 3] = '*';
```

Starting with php7.1 where **negative** string indexes are allowed:

```
$string = "123456789";
// you can rewrite it to a loop too
$string[0] = $string[1] = $string[2] = $string[-1] = $string[-2] = $string[-3] = '*';
echo $string;
```

Solution without **any function**, but it emits `PHP Notice`, you can supress it with `@`:

```
$string = "123456789";
$i = 0;
$limit = 3;
while (true) {
    if ($string[$i] == '') {
        break;
    }

    if ($i < $limit) {
        $string[$i] = '*';
    }
    $i++;
}
/* Simplified version:
while ($string[$i] != '') {
    if ($i < $limit) {
        $string[$i] = '*';
    }
    $i++;
}
*/
$string[$i - 1] = '*';
$string[$i - 2] = '*';
$string[$i - 3] = '*';

echo $string;
```

Comment: are you sure about `isset` function? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364573/php-get-string-length-and-replace-first-and-last-3-characters-without-using-a-fu#comment79688894_46364573

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Not really but I don't see any other way to find end of string.

Comment: the condition is **WITHOUT using any PHP build in functions**

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve it usong loop.(No built-in function)

```
$string = "123456789";
$i = 0;
$new_str = "";
while(true)
{
  $val = @$string[$i];
  if($val == "")
    break;
  if($i<3)
    $new_str .= "*";
  else
    $new_str .= $val;
  $i++;
}


for($j=0;$j<$i;$j++)
{
  if($j >= ($i-3))
    $new_str[$j]="*";
}
echo $new_str;
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/fC5NK)

Answer (score -1):

you can access a string like you would access an array.

```
$var = "leroy jenkins";
$var[2] = 'd';
var_dump($var); // "ledoy jenkins"
```

but I'm currently not sure how to get the last 3 without using a build in function